# Query to determine values not used

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two queries that obtain data from various tables.  Query #1 brings back data that contains ALL answers for 2 specific questions.  Query #2 returns all the possible answers (a defined list).

```
Table Client_Answers ca
QuestionID      AnswerID
1               1
2               3
2               3
2               2
1               2

Table Questions q
QuestionID      QuestionID
1               question #1
2               question #2
3               question #3
4               question #4

Table Answers a
AnswerID        Answer
1               answer abc
2               answer xyz
3               answer 123
4               answer 456
5               answer cba
```

I am ONLY concerned about questions #1 & #2 and can query for them (questions/answers) from the Table Client_Answers.  Now I need to know which possible answers available for questions #1 and #2 have never been used!
I tried using a NOT EXISTS as follows, but it's not returning any data.

```
--Query #1
SELECT q.question
,a.Answer
FROM Client_Answers ca
INNER JOIN Questions q ON q.ID = ca.QuestionID
INNER JOIN Answers a ON a.ID = ca.AnswerID
WHERE ca.ID IN ('1','2')
AND NOT EXISTS
( --Query #2 possible answers
  SELECT 1
FROM Answers a
INNER JOIN Question q ON q.ID = a.QuestionID
WHERE q.ID IN ('1','2')
)
```

I would expect the query to return back

```
answer 456
answer cba
```

What am I not doing correctly?  Not sure if I should be using an EXCEPT statement, but don't know how to use it.  This is running on SQL Server 2008.  Thank you.

Comment: Are all answers in the table `Answers` possible for each question?

Comment: You can use a `LEFT JOIN` and in then check for `NULL` to get what you need.

Comment: @clinomaniac - I've simplified my question as the answers in this table are based on a survey.  I've left that ID and join out for simplicity.  So, yes, let's say all the answers are possible.

Comment: So, you don't have any other relationship between Questions and Answers table, other than the Client_Answers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about this

```
SELECT a.answer
FROM answers AS a
WHERE a.answerID NOT IN 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT ca.answerID
    FROM questions AS q
         inner join
         client_answers AS ca ON ca.questionID=q.questionID
    WHERE questionID in (1,2)
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much everyone!  This did it!

Answer (score 1):

In the simplest form, if your answers are independent from questions (i.e., any question can have any available answer, they're not restricted per-question), the unused answers can be get as:

```
SELECT * FROM Answers
WHERE AnswerId NOT IN (SELECT AnswerId FROM Client_Answers WHERE QuestionId IN (1, 2))
```

If you need these answers per-question, then do

```
SELECT * FROM Answers a, Question q
WHERE AnswerId NOT IN (
    SELECT AnswerId FROM Client_Answers ca WHERE ca.QuestionId = q.QuestionId)
AND QuestionId IN (1,2)
```

Note the cartesian product (might be slow in this case). Also you'll get more results, as e.g. Answer 1 wasn't used for Question 2

Answer (score 0):

I take it the answers can be used for any question, since you don't have a question id in the answer table.  Left joining from the answers to the client answers will give you nulls for the ones that never got used.

```
select a.answerid, a.answer, ca.answerID
  from answers a
left join (select distinct answerid 
             from client_answers where questionid in ('1','2') ) ca
    on a.answerID = ca.answerID
 where ca.answerID is null
```

should do it assuming you don't care about the difference between the answers used for question 1 and the answers used for question 2.